# Clicking child element fires parent click event

Tags: jquery, click

I know this question has been asked a few times, but I cannot seem to get this working. When the child gets click, I don't want the parent event firing. I have the following:

```
<div class="tabItem">
    <span> Item 1</span>
    <div class='contentBody'>Item 2 Body</div>
</div>
```

And the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('.tabItem').each(function(index){                             

                $(this).attr('id', 'tabIndex'+index);               
                var contentDiv = $(this).find('div').first();
                var position = contentDiv.position();
                var right = $(window).width() - position.left - contentDiv.width() ;
                var top = (position.top - 18) ;
                var contentId = 'tabContent' + index;           

                $(contentDiv).css( "display", "none" ).css({top: top, left: 200}).attr('id', contentId);                

                $(this).on('click',  function() {               

                    $(this).removeClass('tabItem').addClass('tabItemSelected');                                         

                     $(currentTab).removeClass('tabItemSelected').addClass('tabItem');  

                    if($('#' + currentContentBody).is(":visible")){
                        $('#' + currentContentBody).toggle( "slide" ); // close the last tab
                    }
                    if($(contentDiv).is(":hidden")){
                        $(contentDiv).toggle( "slide" );    

                    }           
                     currentTab = $(this);
                     currentContentBody = $(contentDiv).attr('id');

                });             
            });

  });
```

The click event is for the parent with class `tabItem`. But when I click the child div, the parent event files. Here is a working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asqwnr8v/2/)

Comment: Go through the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6945909

Comment: You're always sort of clicking a child, as the text is inside spans.

Comment: The function should be attached to the span element not the whole container: ``$(this).find('span').on('click', function(e) {``.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/asqwnr8v/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution is bind the `click` event to the `span`:

```
$(this).find('span').on('click', function(e) {
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/asqwnr8v/3/

Note: Also you need to fix some `$(this)` to `$(this).parent()` inside the `click` event.

Answer (score 6):

You'll want to call [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the child's event handler. This will prevent the event from bubbling up to the parent element.

Be very careful with this, as you can quickly cut of all click-events from bubbling up to the parent if you're not careful. This is clearly *not* what you want.

Comment: Exactly. This prevents child clicks from propagating/bubbling to the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

just change your click handler to this:

```
        $(this).on('click',  function(e) {               

            $(this).removeClass('tabItem').addClass('tabItemSelected');                                         

             $(currentTab).removeClass('tabItemSelected').addClass('tabItem');  

            if($('#' + currentContentBody).is(":visible")){
                $('#' + currentContentBody).toggle( "slide" ); // close the last tab
            }
            if($(contentDiv).is(":hidden")){
                $(contentDiv).toggle( "slide" );    

            }           
             currentTab = $(this);
             currentContentBody = $(contentDiv).attr('id');

            e.stopPropagation();

        });
```

where the important changes are:

> $(this).on('click',  function(e) {

and

> e.stopPropagation();